# I can not restore with transmac

Tags: macos, macos-highsierra

I'm trying to restore MacOS 'High Sieera' to usb using transmac on windows 7 now.

However, the following alerts are displayed and can not be executed.

[image]

The dmg file uses the file downloaded from here.→
https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1946

Answer (score 0):

It's actually moot that you can't use Transmac on that image, as the image itself is a delta updater & not a full installer.

You can only get a full installer from the Apple App Store, for which you will need a Mac.